# Oracle to_number(1234.567)?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to convert a number of type `varchar`(e.g 1234.456) in to floating point number using oracle function to_number(). In my PC (Locale German) the Oracle SQLDeveloper returning number in the fromat `1234,567` instead of `1234.567` and inturn it is causing the oracle error `ORA-01722-invalid number`. I cahnged my system locale to `en_usa` but no use. How can i change the behavior of oracle ?

Help will be greatly appriciated

Comment: Is en_usa a valid locale? I think country codes are 2 char. en_us

Comment: @ John Watts i just mean to english, i set it in windows 7

Comment: Try using nlsparam. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions191.htm

Comment: Or use a format model with an explicit comma instead of 'D'.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142891/how-to-efficiently-convert-text-to-number-in-oracle-pl-sql-with-non-default-nls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT to_number('1234.5678', '9999D9999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=.,')
FROM dual;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/3078) is a fiddle

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. does it worked for you ? for me it did'nt

Comment: @user964147, yes, I added a fiddle so you can see... **Note:** I've put only four digits in my format (`9999`) if you expect more then you should change the format (ie `999999999D99999999`)