# Oracle - String to Double - Dynamic Scale

Tags: sql, oracle

I am in the situation that inside the database various double values are stored as a string.
***(this can not be changed due to some other reasons!)***

The numbers can have a different amount of numbers after & before the decimal separator.
The decimal separator **of the stored values** is a `.`
The default decimal separator **of the database** might possibly change in the future.

**Examples:**

```
1.1  
111.1  
1.111  
11.11  
1.1111
```

I now need to select those as numbers to be able to compare for bigger or smaller values, etc.

Therefore I tried to convert the strings to numbers. I found a hint at this answer: [click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20198185/1342006).

Unfortunately using this as a test:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER('10.123', TRANSLATE('10.123', ' 1,234.567890', TO_CHAR(9999.9, '9G999D9') || '99999'))
FROM DUAL;
```

Somehow converts the number to `10123`, completely removing the decimal separation, so this query gives no result (just for verification):

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT TO_NUMBER('10.123', TRANSLATE('10.123', ' 1,234.567890', TO_CHAR(9999.9, '9G999D9') || '99999')) AS NUM
FROM DUAL) WHERE NUM < 11;
```

---

So I stepped through the single parts to see if I can find an error:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(9999.9, '9G999D9') FROM DUAL; -- 9.999,9

SELECT TO_CHAR(9999.9, '9G999D9') || '99999' FROM DUAL; -- 9.999,999999

SELECT TRANSLATE('10.123', ' 1,234.567890', ' 9.999,999999')
FROM DUAL; -- 99,999

SELECT TRANSLATE('10.123', ' 1,234.567890', TO_CHAR(9999.9, '9G999D9') || '99999')
FROM DUAL; -- 99,999
```

As you can see I get a `.` as group separator and a `,` as decimal separator for the database.

---

I do not understand why it does not correctly convert the number.
Thank you already for any help!

Comment: repeat your test with `alter session set nls_numeric_characters='.,';` I.e. set the decimal separator to '.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this [version](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_number.php) of `to_number`

`TO_NUMBER( string1 [, format_mask] [, nls_language])`

For example:

`SELECT to_number('1.1111','9G990D00000', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''') FROM DUAL`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,';

WITH INPUT_TEST AS (
    SELECT '.' decimal_operator, '1.1' num_in_char from dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '.' decimal_operator, '111.1  ' from dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '.' decimal_operator, '1.111 ' from dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '.' decimal_operator, '11.11  ' from dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '.' decimal_operator, '1.1111' from dual)
SELECT TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(num_in_char, '.', decimal_separator)) to_num
  FROM input_test a, (select SUBSTR(value, 1, 1) decimal_separator 
                        from nls_session_parameters 
                       where parameter = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS') b;

    TO_NUM
----------
       1.1
     111.1
     1.111
     11.11
    1.1111

alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.';

Run the select statement above again.

    TO_NUM
----------
       1,1
     111,1
     1,111
     11,11
    1,1111
```