# How to convert char to number with mask

Tags: oracle, parsing, number-formatting

I can't convert char symbols with dot to number. I get exception

> ORA-01481 invalid format mask

Which mask would work for me? I need unlimited number of characters before the dot.
The star or `n` symbol doesn't work

```
select to_number('840.11', '*.99') from dual
```

Comment: If you want this result then why you are using a format model at all? you can directly convert it to number using -- `to_number('840.11')` trailing .99 in your format model will not have any effect.

Comment: Because of decimal point character, @Tejash. Not everyone uses dot; some use comma. Your code raises an error in my database.

Comment: You can set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS if you want different separator for number at database or session level according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of to_number depends on database or even session settings, so in order to be sure to convert it the way you need, you need to supply the numeric characters, like this:

```
select to_number('840.11', '999.99', ' NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''. ''') from dual
```

Now if you have a higher number of digits before the dot, you can simply enlarge the format mask, like this:

```
select to_number('234234840.11', '99999999999999.99', ' NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''. ''')
from dual
```

There is no direct way to specify a dynamic amount of digits before the dot, but there is some kind of workaround described here:
[Dynamic length on number format in to_number Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196816/dynamic-length-on-number-format-in-to-number-oracle-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You can build a fitting formatmask using `TRANSLATE` and then `ROUND` (or `TRUNC`) the solution of the transformation to your needed accuracy:

```
SELECT ROUND(TO_NUMBER('840.1155',TRANSLATE('840.1155', '123456789', '000000000')),2) FROM dual

=> 840.12
```

Comment: alter session set nls_numeric_characters='.,' - this is work for me